# I want to use outputs from another custom built indicator already on my chart to generate alert in pine script for TV

Tags: pine-script

Let's say I have access to a custom-built indicator `XYZ` on my chart and let's say that `XYZ` suggests some entry prices (let's call it `ee`) on some bars to enter a trade.

I want to make an indicator/alert that needs to call `ee`.

I don't know how to do that.

I did try this code that was referenced to:

```
ExternalIndicator = input(close, "External Indicator")
```

But, in the above code, instead of `close`, I want to use an output of the external indicator.

I don't know how to call that in generating my alert. I do have the custom-built indicator on my chart.

Comment: What you tried should be the correct way to do it, just change the input source of "ExternalIndicator" to the output of the indicator you want to use in the indicator settings.

Comment: How do I do that?  When I do ExternalIndicator = input(ee, "External Indicator") with "ee" being the output of the custom-built indicator a get an error message: Undeclared identifier "ee"